# In WPF how do I apply a style to a third party component

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, componentone, modern-ui

I am using Modern Ui which has styled all my components to have a common look and feel. The standard Richtextbox doesn't support everything I want to do so I am using a 3rd party Richtextbox. The problem is that this 3rd party control doesn't get any style applied. Is there a way to tell this component to apply the same style as the standard richtextbox (which comes from the modern ui style)

Comment: What third party provider are you using? Also, please add relevant code

Comment: There is no general way this is handled - it all depends on which third party components you are using. In my experience, vendors of such components are usually quick to update their components with new styles.

Comment: Im using the component one richtextbox

Comment: I haven't tried the components from ComponentOne, so I cannot help you. Try searching through their forums, or search StackOverflow with the "ComponentOne" tag included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component One has documentation for setting basic appearance properties.

[Clear Style Properties](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1richtextboxwpf/#!WordDocuments/c1richtextboxclearst.htm)

As well as predefined Themes for their controls.

[C1 RitchTextBox Themes](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1richtextboxwpf/default.htm#!WordDocuments/c1richtextboxthemes.htm)

If these don't offer you the level of control over the appearance of the C1RitchTextBox you would probably need to override the Template for this control.

[MS Styling and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

Alternately you may look for documentation on creating your own themes for C1 controls on their site.